# Landscape comment entry does not wrap

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

When entering a comment, the text field is taller than one line, but the text never wraps. It scrolls horizontally on a single line instead, which is quite frustrating if you are trying to scan for mistakes before you post, edit something, etc.

This only happens in landscape mode. In portrait, the comment box starts as one line, then auto-expands and wraps as it should. In landscape, it starts multi-line and never uses any but the first. Similar text fields in other apps wrap just fine, so if it's something particular to my phone/version, it only seems to happen in the SE app.

Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.2.2, App 0.1.84

I tagged this as a bug because I feel it's just *wrong*. If this is intended behavior, let me know and I'll change it to a feature request.

Comment: Its useful to post the app version. You can see it by tapping the menu button, and going to "help".

Comment: Good point, added to question.

Comment: I could reproduce this on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, App 1.0.82 (beta). However, it's a bit more complex than this: the bug only occurs on keyboard apps *which request [fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523372/), regardless of its orientation (portrait/landscape)* (tried on Google Keyboard on landscape, and Google Japanese IME on portrait & landscape). Also, it will correctly wrap after changing the orientation (only for a workaround, the bug itself is legit).